# How to get response from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm working with a system that assigns files to users. Problem is, that the response, userid, is always 0.

```
$user = htmlentities($_SESSION['username']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `files`(
`userid`, 
`filename`, 
`filesize`, 
`filetype`, 
`filepath`
) 
VALUES 
(\"". get_user_id($user). "\",\"". 
$_FILES['userfile']['name']. "\",\"". 
$_FILES['userfile']['size']. "\",\"". 
$_FILES['userfile']['type']. "\",\"". 
$fileadress. 
"\")";
```

Function get_user_id

```
function get_user_id($user){
mysql_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD)
or die(mysql_error());

$sqlinit = "USE secure_login";
mysql_query($sqlinit);

$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '". $user."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
//mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo mysql_error();
$userid = $result;
return $userid;
}
```

No errors, no warnings, everything else is working fine, only userid is showing always 0, even when id in members is 1,2 etc. Am I missing something? In both tables, userid and id are int.

Comment: Why `htmlentities` the username? You should use the mysql_real_escape_string function on the user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns you a mysql object, you put this object in the result variable. So if you do `$userid = $result;` you just duplicate the array to a new variable.

You're not accessing correctly to the element, you should write instead : `$userid = $result['id'];`

Take the habit to employ `var_dump($result);` to see what's exactly in you're variable (here result)

EDIT:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = '". $user."'";
$queryRes = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($queryRes);
$userid = $result['id'];
```

Comment: I've changed the code to your suggestions, and `echo var_dump($result);` returned `resource(9) of type (mysql result)`

Comment: Oh... I didn't notice `mysql_fetch_array($result);` is commented.

`$sql = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = '". $user."'";
$queryRes = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($queryRes);
$userid = $result['id'];`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use `$userid=$result['id']`

Answer (score 0):

As per your table, the right index would be `userid`

i.e:

```
$userid = $result['id'];
```

Comment: How did/do you decipher the column is `userid`?

Comment: `files` and `members` are 2 different tables.

Comment: My bad...didn't noticed